# Can you delete external cookies in php

Tags: php, cookies

I am developing a web app and I would like to delete an external cookie in the browser(one from Yahoo). I have tried print_r($_COOKIE); , which is supposed to print all cookie the, but it only prints the cookies that I created, is there anyway to access other cookies??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete or view or edit external site COOKIES using PHP. But you can delete cookies by clearing your browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

No - this isn't possible - for privacy and security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access other domains cookies.  There is no such thing as cross domain cookies.